# access to a json value

Tags: javascript, json, syntax

I've a little misunderstanding with json/js syntax

This is my json :

```
var paramsField = {
    "params" : [
        {
            "data" : {
                "date" : "2014-05-03 00:00:00"
            }
        }
     ]
}
```

It's not my file, i just access it with angularjs http and it's ok.
I want to access to the date value, and i try

```
var dataD = data.paramsField.params[0].data.date;
```

i have Cannot read property 'params' of undefined error, what's the correct syntax ?

Comment: FIY, this is not JSON, this is a JavaScript object.

Comment: it's like Sajad's solution, and it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

```
var dataD = data.paramsField.params[0].data.date;
```

should read

```
var dataD = paramsField.params[0].data.date;
```